# How to use unsigned int to be able to use a function for JNA (Java Native Interface)?

Tags: java, function, int, jna, unsigned

I'm using JNA in order to use a C++ library in my Java application.  I am using an interface in Java to use these functions.  The function uses three arguments in C++: an unsigned int, a const char*, and a long*.  JNA implements Strings (according to their documents) in Java to pass in a char*.  Likewise, it uses a long[] to pass in a long*.  I'm confused, however, about the type that I should pass in for the unsigned int.  The char* that is passed in represents the name of the file, and no matter what type I use for the first argument, it does not seem to recognize the file.  Furthermore, the last, long type actually returns a value after the function is executed.  If I use the short or int type for the first argument, this number seems to be correct, however, if I use the long type for the first argument, it is incorrect.  Can anyone help?

For an example, here's what the actual prototype in C++ is followed by what I currently have as the interface prototype in Java:

```
int JrConnect(unsigned int id, const char* config_file, long* handle);

public int JrConnect(int[] id, String[] config_file, long[] handle);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JNA's  [IntByReference](http://jna.java.net/javadoc/com/sun/jna/ptr/IntByReference.html).

Comment: Doesn't this require the unsigned int to be a pointer to unsigned int?