# How should I pass and return unsigned int by value from Java to C/C++ in jna

Tags: java, c++, c, jna

My C++ function

```
extern "C" {
   DECLSPEC unsigned int STDCALL doNumberThing(unsigned int some_number);
}
```

My Java Interface

```
package com.myplace.nativeapi;

import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.Memory;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

interface NativeAPI extends Library {
    int doNumberThing(int some_number);
}
```

Obviously this has a problem when dealing with values that are only valid for one or the other of the mismatched types (int vs unsigned int); what is the recommended way to get around this? [One answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5627334/14250) recommends "IntByReference", but unless I've misunderstood, they're talking about the long*, not the actual unsigned int being passed by value.

(This is trimmed down example code, if there's a syntax error, let me know in the comments and I'll update the question)

Comment: C is not C++ is not C!

Comment: @Olaf While true, this answer would work for both C and C++, so people who only follow the C and Java tags could answer it; and people who need to solve this problem for a C API could also use the answers; but thanks for reminding me that I need to stick the extern C around the call.

Comment: Why do you believe there is "a signage problem"? Conversion between int and unsigned is a NOP.

Comment: If you have to add `extern "C" { ... }`, it is not C++ then. Either way, there is only one of the tags correct. And what do you mean with "signage"? It is likely a signedness-problem. I don't know Java, but if it has no unsigned types, you need space for the extra bit `unsigned` in C provides for one direction, or have to assert the value is never negative the other direction.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Maybe I've misunderstood, but what happens when you get a large unsigned number in C coming back, or pass a negative number from the Java. Obviously the second can be blocked by pre-call checks, but the first appears to be insuperable.

Yes, for "normal" values, I'm fine, but having a signed/unsigned mismatch is sloppy if avoidable, and that's why the question reads "Should" and not "Do"; this is a question about the "correct" way to solve this issue.

Comment: @Olaf ...This may be a discussion for meta; I appreciate if you don't know Java and the JNA library, then this might be not the question for you; but in essence: Java has an interop library to interface with C code; and if you're working with C++, the most sensible thing to do is to simply create a C-compliant interface (as above). Therefore, this question is answerable and applicable to anyone who has experience interfacing C **OR** C++ and Java, and anyone trying to solve this issue in either language; hence the tagging.

Comment: @Olaf The C interface makes sense, the value can never be negative. [Java does not have an unsigned integer](http://www.nayuki.io/page/unsigned-int-considered-harmful-for-java), therefore this interop code has an innate flaw. I would like to fix the flaw, and am asking for help with this, as there isn't an obvious solution.  Has the site changed since I was last here, or isn't this still a site for helping programmers find solutions to their problems?

Comment: Simply change the "C++ function" so it uses `int` rather than `unsigned int`.   That way there is not a mismatch of interfaces.    Trying to find hackery to work through a mismatch of interface is error prone, and likely to fail when porting code between systems.   Since Java doesn't support an unsigned type, the C++ code must handle conversions, rather than trying to rely on conversion happening by magic in the interface specification.

Comment: @Peter Sure, but that's "breaking" the interoperability interface, also used by C#, merely to support Java's missing types. More importantly, as the JNA Library is specifically designed to solve interop, it must have a recommended way to interact with *locked down* API's which use unsigned int

Comment: @deworde: Well, I was right then with my comment. If you need the whole range of `unsigned`, you have to provide a way to pass the extra bit of the value to Java, thus use a larger signed type (or pass the bit in an extra variable - which would be pretty hacky, but might be required if there is no extra variable). **Iff** (!) you can guarantee not to exceed the range of the Java signed variable, you are fine, of course.

Comment: If java sees a negative integer, simply add `1L<<32` and you'll get a long with the proper value.

Comment: @Olaf To be clear, my question is "How *should* I do this when using JNA?", not "can I hack something together using bit shifting and value checking?" I *know* I can do the latter, I just don't want to unless there's no better way.

Comment: @Olaf Also, I can't let this go; "If you have to add extern "C" { ... }, it is not C++ then" is in contention for the least accurate comment I have ever read on stackoverflow. externC *literally* only has any meaning in C++; just because it's making it C interop doesn't mean it's suddenly become C code.

Comment: You are asing about the **function**, not the surrounding. So: if you have to put the function into `extern "C"` braces, the function is clearly C, not C++. You have the last word.

Comment: @deworde: I'm not sure if I have understood the whole conversation thoroughly well but hey !! Is it possible to pass some extra information to the java interface? If possible why not pass the type?

Comment: @Olaf If I get the last word, [I'll outsource](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/300165/14250) it to [smarter people](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252433/14250).

Comment: @sjsam I could do, passing additional data, and if I have to, I will, but my feeling is that JNA, being a C/C++ interop library, will already have the ability to do something like this, it's just that the [google search](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jna%20unsigned%20int) isn't helpful. Hence asking this question. To be honest, in my case, the numbers are involved are between 0 and 3, so this really is just a best practices question, somewhat derailed in the comments.

Comment: @deword:following up on your reply 20 hours ago. Java does not support unsigned types because the designers deem they make things too complicated for programmers, and that philosophy affects JNA.  So little chance of a solution in JNA. If you can't change the legacy interface on the C side, you need to provide ANOTHER interface that works with JNA, and route between old and new on the C/C++/C# sides. Think facade pattern.  Or, bite the bullet, change the interface to be compatible with Java, and update all code which uses the old interface to use the new one. Yes, ugly, but few other choices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JNA provides the `IntegerType` class](http://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.1/), which can be used to indicate an unsigned integer of some particular size.  You'll have to use a Java `long` to hold a native `unsigned int` in primitive form, since its values may be outside the range of Java `int`, but in general you can pass around the `IntegerType` object and only pull the primitive value out as needed.

```
public class UnsignedInt extends IntegerType {
    public UnsignedInt() {
         super(4, true);
    }
}
```